Azure AI Search Scoring Profiles are not modifying the score retrival
I have been using Azure Ai search and scoring profiles to boost the documents of my index that come form the 'reviewed' source that means I want to send to the very TOP documents that have the string 'reviewed' on the field source, so I configured this scoring profile:
  "scoringProfiles": [
    {
      "name": "pubs_peer_house",
      "functionAggregation": "sum",
      "text": {
        "weights": {
          "title": 3,
          "content": 10
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "fieldName": "source",
          "interpolation": "linear",
          "type": "tag",
          "boost": 100,
          "freshness": null,
          "magnitude": null,
          "distance": null,
          "tag": {
            "tagsParameter": "reviewed"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

I have this code in Python:
from azure.core.exceptions import HttpResponseError

# Define the search query
search_query = "cybersecurity in Arizona from tech today"

# Function to get the embedding of the search query
search_vector = get_embedding(search_query)

# Define the scoring parameters
scoring_parameters = ["reviewed-100"]  

try:
    # Perform the search using the Azure Cognitive Search client
    response = search_client.search(
        search_query, 
        top=5,  # Return the top 5 results
        vector_queries=[
            VectorizedQuery(
                vector=search_vector,  # The vector representation of the search query
                k_nearest_neighbors=5,  # Number of nearest neighbors to find
                fields="vector_space_search"  # Field in the index to search the vector space
            )
        ],
        query_type="semantic",  # Specify the query type as semantic
        semantic_configuration_name=semantic_profile,  # The name of the semantic configuration
        scoring_profile='pubs_peer_house',  # The scoring profile to use
        scoring_parameters=scoring_parameters  # The scoring parameters
    )

    # Iterate over the search results
    for idx, doc in enumerate(response, start=1):
        # Default values if fields are not found
        found_content = "Not found"
        
        # Extract fields from the search result
        date = doc.get('date', 'N/A')  # Date of the document
        source = doc.get('source', 'N/A')  # Source of the document
        title = doc.get('title', 'N/A')  # Title of the document
        content = doc.get('content', 'N/A')  # Content of the document
        
        # Print the results
        print(f"{idx}")
        print(f"Score: {doc['@search.score']:.5f}")
        print(f"Source: {source}")
        print(f"Title: {title}")
        print(f"Content: {content}\n\n")
except HttpResponseError as e:
    # Handle HTTP response errors
    print(f"HTTP Response Error: {e.message}")
    print(f"Details: {e.response}")
except Exception as ex:
    # Handle other exceptions
    print(f"An error occurred: {ex}")

Nonetheless when I ask for anything and I implement my profiles scoring along with the semantic ranker in a hybrid search it doesn't matter the value of the booster. I always get the same results:
Look:

1 Score: 0.03667 Source: americas Subtitle: What level of
cybersecurity do you have? Content: We comply with industry standards
for cybersecurity and recommend that you...
2 Score: 0.02639 Source: reviewed Subtitle: What do I need to operate
securely? Content: The key or security signature. It is an 8-digit
alphanumeric code ML te....
3 Score: 0.01562 Source: europe Subtitle: Passkey password and pin
still better than faceID Content: careful whose face do you trust....

even with params like : scoring_parameters = ["reviewed-2500000"]    I still get:

1 Score: 0.03667
Source: americas
Subtitle: What level of
cybersecurity do you have? Content: We comply with industry standards
for cybersecurity and recommend that you...
2 Score: 0.02639 Source: reviewed Subtitle: What do I need to operate
securely? Content: The key or security signature. It is an 8-digit
alphanumeric code ML te....
3 Score: 0.01562 Source: europe Subtitle: Passkey password and pin
still better than faceID Content: careful whose face do you trust....

Am I doing something wrong? I can't seem to find a tutorial on this in Python online.
This is my Index Config:
    "name": "idx_americas_europe_pubs_houses",
  "defaultScoringProfile": null,
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "content",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "title",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "source",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "pub_date",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "vector_space_search",
      "type": "Collection(Edm.Single)",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": 1536,
      "vectorSearchProfile": "embedding_profile",
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_path",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": true,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    }
  ],
   "scoringProfiles": [
    {
      "name": "pubs_peer_house",
      "functionAggregation": "sum",
      "text": {
        "weights": {
          "title": 3,
          "content": 10
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "fieldName": "source",
          "interpolation": "linear",
          "type": "tag",
          "boost": 100,
          "freshness": null,
          "magnitude": null,
          "distance": null,
          "tag": {
            "tagsParameter": "reviewed"
          }
        }
      ]
  ]
    }
  ],
  "corsOptions": null,
  "suggesters": [],
  "analyzers": [],
  "normalizers": [],
  "tokenizers": [],
  "tokenFilters": [],
  "charFilters": [],
  "encryptionKey": null,
  "similarity": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.BM25Similarity",
    "k1": null,
    "b": null
  },
  "semantic": {
    "defaultConfiguration": null,
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "ranker_profile_pubs",
        "prioritizedFields": {
          "titleField": {
            "fieldName": "title"
          },
          "prioritizedContentFields": [
            {
              "fieldName": "content"
            }
          ],
          "prioritizedKeywordsFields": []
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "vectorSearch": {
    "algorithms": [
      {
        "name": "hnsw_config",
        "kind": "hnsw",
        "hnswParameters": {
          "metric": "cosine",
          "m": 3,
          "efConstruction": 300,
          "efSearch": 250
        },
        "exhaustiveKnnParameters": null
      }
    ],
    "profiles": [
      {
        "name": "embedding_profile",
        "algorithm": "hnsw_config",
        "vectorizer": null,
        "compression": null
      }
    ],
    "vectorizers": [],
    "compressions": []
  }
}


please share your index in json fromat.

Sampath! Thanks I just added the index config thanks for you amaizng help

in Query  can you change search_query  to  source and try  with source data once.

Im so sorry It didnt help at all, I just noticed that If I dont do a hybrid search (vector+text) it works! if I only do a text simple query it works but if I do a hybrid search it doesnt.. what do you think is that?? is there a bug or the code is incorrect? Thanks a million sampath

Can you share sample outputs/inputs you given from Data sources

Actually, you need to give the scoring parameter in below format.
<name>-<comma-separated values>
Here, name is the parameter name. You can see in below image it is catTag.

Next, values you need in the given field should be comma separated.
So, check you index scoring profiles. if you having more than 1 scoring parameter then you need to give in list like below.
["<1st_parameter_name>-<values>","<2nd_parameter_name>-<values>"]
Here are the sample output
I have 2 scoring function of type tag.

Output:


This is correct and this works for me but I want to apply the scoring profile in a hybrid search look that you only have a text search so its using the BM25 algo, if you try that in a hibryd search it does not work is like a bug or something

Ok. What error it is showing?
